# How to get the User pool token from Hosted UI on AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am wanting to use the Hosted UI option in AWS Cognito so I don't have to build my own login page.

Most Cognito examples I see include custom built login pages using the [Amplify-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js) framework. **I'm trying to avoid this approach.**

For my project, I have selected the Hosted UI option in AWS Cognito and upon successful login, I am redirected to my React application. However I'm unaware of how to retrieve the user pool token at this point. Looking in my chrome developer tab, I don't see any tokens under local storage, session storage, cookies, etc.

**How can I find this token?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token is returned as a query parameter `id_token` while redirecting to your application.
Refer to the docs for more details: [using the hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html)

Comment: You are correct. In my case, I was using the URL with response_type=code, hence I was not receiving the id_token field. 
After changing to response_type=token, I started receiving the id_token field. Thanks!